# Find the exact time of a credit card purchase with Chase

Tags: credit-card

I need to find the exact time when a credit card purchase was made. This is not the "Transaction date" or the "Post date", I need the authorization time.

I know this data is available because I have push alerts set up on iPhone and I get a push notification immediately when making a purchase. iPhone does not save push notifications with a timestamp and the app only shows the date.

I have a parking ticket in Philadelphia, the machine shows a time of 6:11pm and the ticket is from 7:12pm. If the machine was off 30 seconds, I will save $40 with your advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would call Chase card services and ask them directly. Tell them plainly what you need, you might be surprised. Often their screens have much more detailed information than what you can see via their Web site or mobile app.

Comment: whenever my Chase credit card gets charged I see the exact time in amount  email to me as a result I would think that that information is available when you call them up

Answer (score 3):

The meter maid was waiting for your meter to expire when you get the ticket. Some meters are "smart" these days and will even text the meter maid the meter is about to expire. Even if the push notification was delayed by 30 seconds, how is that going to help your situation? You're not going to get your $40 back.

I was able to have a ticket dismissed one time because the ticket printer machine was off by 12 hours (3:00AM instead of 3:00PM when the ticket was issued). I was able to argue that parking is free at 3:00AM. :) Your situation is much different. The meter maid gave you a ticket after 60 minutes.